# Spring Cloud Stream - One To Many Transformation

Tags: list, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I have a simple Spring Cloud Stream application where the stream accepts a raw JSON string and produces a list of Objects.

Version used :

```
<spring.cloud.version>Hoxton.SR2</spring.cloud.version>
```

Signature of stream used:

```
@Bean
public Function<String, List<EmailEvent>> normalizeStream() {
  return value -> {
    return getNormalizedEvents(value);
  };
}
```

Expectation is that although the output signature of the stream is a List, it should be serialized as individual items in the queue. This change is perfectly working in this version of Cloud stream.

But when I upgrade to **Hoxton.SR4** or above, this expectation is breaking and the producer is producing as a list only instead of individual items.

Any help on what I might be missing would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I mean that the thing is in the method signature that you're using.

With this version the results are as expected. Check examples below.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0-RC1</version>
</parent>
```

**1st CASE. One to Many (wrapped in a list)**

In this first example, each String message produces a Message with a `List<String>` Object Payload that is sent to kafka.

```
@Bean
    public Function<String, List<String>> oneToMany() {
        return str -> {
            return List.of(str, "custom");
        };
    }
```

Reading output topic with kafkacat:

```
 % Reached end of topic one-to-many [0] at offset 180
["a","custom"]
```

**2ns CASE. One to Many (one by one)**

In this other example (I think that is what you're looking for) each string is converted to a List and then each item in that `List<Message<<String>>` is sent to kafka by the binding bridge.

```
@Bean
    public Function<String, List<Message<String>>> oneToMany() {
        return str -> {
            return List.of(MessageBuilder.withPayload(str).build(), MessageBuilder.withPayload("custom").build());
        };
    }
```

Reading output topic with kafkacat:

```
 % Reached end of topic one-to-many [0] at offset 185
a
custom
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But I am not seeing any difference in the 2 examples you provided. Might be a mistake in pasting. Can you please share the correct example? TIA

Comment: Yes, typo error. I've updated first example.

Comment: This solved my problem. Thank you so much for your help!!